# C++: When is a destructor called before the last statement?

Tags: c++, destructor

So I have some C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    C() {i = 9; cout << "C0:" << i << endl;}

    C(int i0) {i = i0; cout << "C1:" << i << endl;}

    ~C() {cout << "C2:" << i << endl;}
private:
    int i;
};

void f(int i) {
    C c(i);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i  = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cout << "X" << endl;
        f(i);
        cout << "Y" << endl;
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
X
C1:0
C2:0
Y
```

This is strange because the line C2:0 is part of the destructor which I've learned is called after the last statement. So my question is in what kind of situations are destructors called before the last statement?

Comment: scope of object c is the function F，not main，not for loop

Comment: The last statement in the scope where `c` is defined is `C c(i);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object `C` is created inside function f. So, `C` is destroyed when the `f` function scope ends, simply right after calling `f(i)` in main, `f` scope is destroyed, and the `C` object's destructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic variables (your `c` in `f()`), are cleaned up when the stack they are on goes away.

So in this case, it's as your `f(i)` call is returning.  For objects, this includes calling the destructor.

Globals and static variables are also cleaned up as your program exits, when it exits properly.  If it exits via an uncaught exception, they may not be cleaned up (it's not required).

Answer (score 0):

> This is strange because the line C2:0 is part of the destructor which I've learned is called after the last statement.

The destructor is called after the last statement **of the scope containing the variable which is an instance of a class.**

Answer (score 0):

`C` is created and destroyed within the scope of the `f(int i)` function so the destructor of C prints "C2:0". f finishes and only then Y is printed.